# Choppy movement with ruby Gosu and Chingu

Tags: ruby, game-physics, libgosu

I'm doing a tile based RPG type game where the tiles (including the characters) are all `50x50`. I haven't used chingu before, but taking a look at the docs, I have this:

```
class Player < Chingu::GameObject
  def initialize(options)
  end
  def move_left
    @x -= 50
  end
  def move_right
    @x += 50
  end
 end
 class Game < Chingu::Window
   def initialize
     super
     @player = Player.create
     @player.input = {:left => :move_left, :right => :move_right}
   end
 end
```

Using this movement there's no fluidity between steps. Now, doing the standard `while key_down?(:left); move_left; end` type deal, and then just moving the character at smaller intervals makes it smooth, but the issue ends up being that the character is able to stop between grid lines (if that makes sense).

It seems the `move_left` and `move_right` need to return the value of `@x`, so doing recursion inside that method doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas, or should I just not use chingu and try and figure out the logic inside the `draw` method?